# Data/IO communication between Perl and Matlab

Tags: perl, matlab, io, communication

I am an active user of MATLAB and Perl, where I use MATLAB as the platform to run main programs, as well as to call other scripts like Perl and Java Class.

**However, I've never found a good way to reuse the output from Perl in Matlab, without using an CSV/Excel/txt file as an IO median.**

I really appreciate any ideas in facilitating the communication between Perl and Matlab. 
Alternatively, can you suggest other similar languages that is convenient to work with Matlab?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Qiao.

Answer (score 3):

from Matlab help I learned to use `eval()`.

So let's say your perl script `multiply.plx` executes

```
$a=$ARGV[0];

$b=$ARGV[1];

$result=$a*$b;

print "$result";
```

In Matlab just call

```
a=perl('multiply.plx','2','3');
b=eval(a);
```

Variable `a` will be a string, while variable `b` is a number. However, this works only for scalars, I was not able to convert a list/hash of numbers to a matrix/vector.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the built-in function [PERL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/perl.html). It runs the supplied Perl script and returns the result:

```
[result,status] = perl('hello.pl','World')
```

where

#### hello.pl

```
$input = $ARGV[0]; 
print "Hello $input.";
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs!

But then the result will just be a string containing all the print clause results, we need to further process it in order to get meaning data. It's not easy to use in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried java as an intermediary?
Something like

```
x      = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
process= x.exec('/bin/perl params');
reader = java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
...
reader.readLine()
```

You could potentially do the same with the outputstream to send data to perl? Seems relatively straightforward though perhaps not the most economical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of call Perl from Matlab, I may suggest calling Matlab from Perl. To that end, I recommend [Inline::Octave](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline%3a%3aOctave). Hopefully your Matlab code can run in Octave without much overhaul.

I had a success story of building a mid-size scientific program using Perl and Octave together. Perl is good for collecting data, preparing the input for Octave script and batch processing. Octave code can only focus on the core of computing task. [PDL](https://metacpan.org/module/PDL) is another option but I switched back to Octave since the rewrite of the original code was too hard.